# Which browsers support the for...of loop over an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Which browsers support the new ES6 for...of loop?  CanIUse does not have an entry for it and I'd prefer to use a for...of than a for...in over my array.

Thanks!

Comment: look at browser compatibility in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site has a somewhat comprehensive list of such things. Use the following url to see for..of

http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#for..of_loops

Note that the row expands to show details about the support.